# VBO best methods OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, vbo

Does it make more sense to store the coordinates for a single cube in a VBO and use camera translation/rotation to place each block in its proper place on the map, or does it make more sense to store the entire map in a VBO  and just draw from that?

It's not a minecraft clone, but it is a 3rd person top-down camera angle world that builds terrain from cubes

Comment: If you're making a Minecraft clone, please say so. It makes it a lot easier to know why you're asking about cubes and what your terrain will entail.

Comment: I've always wondered about using the world space coordinates for texturing and just using instancing to build buildings from stretched blocks....

Comment: it's definitely not a minecraft clone, but it does use a lot of cubes as part of the terrain.  It's a 3rd person top-down camera angle with cubes building the terrain

Comment: i'll be honest i dont know the difference between voxel and octree

Comment: ROT: batching always wins! Good luck with your engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply taking the question at face-value, it seems to me the OP is considering a multi-pass render scheme vs rendering large amounts of geometry using VBOs.

If this is correct, then rendering large amounts of geometry will win over a multi-pass rendering scheme. Of course, the correct way to efficiently render many cubes is to batch them by material(s) and perform [instanced rendering](http://sol.gfxile.net/instancing.html).

Comment: thanks, I think that's what I was looking at.  Didn't know the official terminology for it.  I'll take a look at instanced rendering, thanks.